# What does this awk script do

Tags: awk

```
echo 1 | awk '{ srand(); print int (rand()*67) }'
```

I get a different o/p everytime I run it. However if I omit the 1 I get same o/p ..why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this on OS X.  With or without the 1 I get random output.

Comment: you are right polynomial!

Comment: The outcome of `srand()` varies once per second (it seeds the pseudorandom number generator based on the whole number of seconds since the origin of time), which explains why you might have seen the same output twice if you ran the command twice in quick succession.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It prints a random number between 1 and 67. It could also have been written without the `echo`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{srand(); print int(rand()*67+1)}'
```

See the [Gnu Awk Users Guide](http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Numeric-Functions.html):

> srand([x])
> Set the starting point, or seed, for generating random numbers to the value x.